# Reference for the Law of the Unconscious Statistician?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

Does anyone know of a reference (a book or journal article) for the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)?

Comment: A reference for the weird name or for the simple fact?

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243529/what-is-the-name-of-this-theorem-and-are-there-any-caveats/243651#comment537508_243651).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Israel gives a reference [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6787131). It is Ross' book "Introduction to Probability Models", but it is only in Ed. 1-3.