# transform matrix to have orthogonal columns

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to transform $\mathbf{L}_{mn} = \mathbf{l}^1, \dots, \mathbf{l}^n$, so that the element wise multiplication of elements in two different columns is zero $\sum^m_{r=1}\mathbf{l}^i_r \mathbf{l}^j_r=0 \quad i\neq j \quad \text{and} \quad i,j \in 1, \dots, n$. Probably the same as saying orthogonal columns.

I am looking for different possibilities to achieve that, because I would like to also preserve some properties of $\mathbf{L}$.

Possibilities I have found so far:

- Gram-Schmidt Orthogonolization
- $\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{L}*m)^{-1/2}$

**What are other possibilities to orthogonalize the columns of a matrix?**

---

Background.
These properties are already fullfilled and I would like that they are still fullfilled after a transformation.

column means are zero
$$\sum_{r=1}^m l_r^{i} = 0 \qquad i \in 1, \dots, n$$
standard deviation per column zero
$$\sum_{r=1}^m (l_r^{i})^2 = 1 \qquad i \in 1, \dots, n$$
skewness first column is $\mathbf{b}_1$
$$\quad \sum_{r=1}^m (l_r^{1})^3 = \mathbf{b}_1$$
co-skewness first column and any other column equal $\mathbf{b}_i$
$$\sum_{r=1}^m (l_r^{1})^2 l_r^{i}  = \mathbf{b}_i \qquad i \in 2, \dots, n$$

Comment: Your second condition on the columns implies that $\mathbf{l}^{i}=0$ if they have real entries. Are these complex matrices? Also, by counting the number of free parameters and number of equations, it seems that you need $m\geq (n+5)/2$ (but it's possible that some of these equations end up being dependent, so the true lower bound might be somewhat smaller).

Comment: all entries are real and this matrix represents a sample normally of size 10000 or higher so this shouldn't be a problem. You could also say the equations mean, that each mean is 0 each standard deviation 1, skewness of first column equal b1 and co-skewness(column1, colum1, column i) = bi.

Comment: You should edit the second equation so that it equals 1, rather than 0, in that case.