# Generate three random variable to have specific coskewness

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

I want to generate three random variable X, Y, and Z that have a specific coskewness. I am defining coskewness between three random variable instead of between two random variable which seems to be more common:

$\displaystyle S(X,Y,Z)={\frac{E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])(Z-E[Z])]}{\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\sigma_{Z}}}$

As I understand it, mean and std are Sufficient statistic for a gaussian distribution so higher order statistics are not unique and can be calculated using only those two; Am I correct? and if so does that mean for my case, I need to look into other pdf families?

I have seen this question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413280/co-skewness-find-random-v-with-co-skewness-to-another-r-v) but not sure how I can use it for three r.v.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we want a coskewness of $\xi$. If $\xi=0$, this is easy. Just take $X,Y,Z\sim N(0,1)$ independent.

For $\alpha> 0$, there exists a random variable $A$ with mean zero, variance $1$, and $\mathbb{E}(A^4)=\alpha^2+1$. To see this, define $f(t)=\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}$ for $t\geqslant 1$. Note that $f(1)=1$, $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\infty$, and $f$ is continuous. Therefore for any $0<\alpha<\infty$, since $f(1)=1<\alpha^2+1<\infty$,  there exists $t>1$ such that $$\alpha^2+1 = \frac{t^3+1}{t+1}.$$  Let $A$ be a random variable taking the values $-1$, $0$, and $t$ according to $$\mathbb{P}(A=a)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{t}{t^2+t} & : a = -1 \\ \frac{1}{t^2+t} & : a = t \\ \frac{t^2-1}{t^2+t} & : a = 0.\end{array}\right.$$

Then $$\mathbb{E}(A)=t\cdot \frac{1}{t^2+t} -1\cdot \frac{t}{t^2+t} =0,$$ $$\mathbb{E}(A^2) = t^2\cdot \frac{1}{t^2+t}+1\cdot \frac{t}{t^2+t}=1,$$
$$\mathbb{E}(A^4) = t^4\cdot \frac{1}{t^2+t}+1\cdot \frac{t}{t^2+t}=\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}=\alpha^2+1.$$

Let $X=A$, $Y=A$, and $$Z=A^2-1.$$  Then $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(Z)=0.$$ Moreover, $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y=1$ and $\sigma_Z=\alpha$.  This is because $$\text{Var}(Z)=\text{Var}(A^2)=\mathbb{E}(A^4)-\mathbb{E}(A^2)^2=\alpha^2+1-1=\alpha^2,$$ and $\sigma_Z=\sqrt{\alpha^2}=\alpha$.

Note that $$XYZ=A^4-A^2,$$ which has mean $\alpha^2+1-1=\alpha^2$. Since $X,Y,Z$ are mean zero, the coskewness is $\alpha^2/\alpha=\alpha$.

Fix $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\xi=0$, let $X,Y,Z$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables, which gives coskewnss $0=\xi$.

If $\xi\neq 0$, let $\alpha=|\xi|$ and let $X,Y,Z$ be as above with this $\alpha$. Then if $\xi>0$, $X,Y,Z$ have coskewness $\alpha=\xi$. If $\xi<0$, $-X,Y,Z$ have coskewness $-\alpha=\xi$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have two question: I am not sure how E(A) is calculated. shouldn't t be multiplied by $\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+t}$. I am not sure where the $t^2-1$ in the numerator has gone. additionally, is there no way we can do this for independent random variable? I understand if they are independent and come from $\textbf{gaussian}$ distribution coskewness is zero, but what about other distributions?

Comment: If $X,Y,Z$ are independent, $$\mathbb{E}((X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)(Z-\mu_Z)) = \mathbb{E}(X-\mu_X)\mathbb{E}(Y-\mu_Y)\mathbb{E}(Z-\mu_Z)=0\cdot 0 \cdot 0 =0.$$

Comment: For your question about $\mathbb{E}(A)$, you are correct. I had my probabilities for $A=0$ and $A=t$ switched. I've fixed it.

Comment: Tnx. in your answer how do we get t? is it a random variable? if so what is its pdf. and does the way we sample from the pdf matters?

Comment: To get coskewness with absolute value $\alpha>0$, you get $t$ by solving  $$\alpha^2+1=\frac{t^3+1}{t+1}.$$

Comment: $t$ isn't a random variable. It just depends in a deterministic way on the $\alpha$ you want.

Comment: So does this mean A can only take 3 values? 0, -1 and t?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understood your response. Just a question through. do you know of any multivariate pdf that coskewness is part of its sufficient statistic? I essentially want the random variable to take any possible values rather than only three values.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a thing. I'm typically aware of sufficient statistics as being part of a random sample consisting of iid entries, and coskewness is always $0$ for independent rvs. However, you can modify my example to take random variables $P,Q,R$, where $P$ is a mixture of $X$ and $X'$, $Q$ is a mixture of $Y$ and $Y'$, and $R$ is a mixture of $Z$ and $Z'$, where $X,Y,Z$ are as above and $X',Y',Z'$ are normals that are independent of each other and of $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: the weight of the mixing can be anything?

Comment: Pick $p\in (0,1)$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Pick $X,Y,Z$ to have coskewness $\alpha/p$. Pick $X',Y',Z'$ with mean zero, the same variances as $X,Y,Z$, respectively, and which are independent of each other and independent of $X,Y,Z$. Let $(P,Q,R)=(X,Y,Z)$ with probability $p$ and $(P,Q,R)=(X',Y',Z')$ with probability $1-p$. Then $$\mathbb{E}[P_CQ_CR_C]=p\mathbb{E}[X_CY_CZ_C]+(1-p)\mathbb{E}[X'Y'Z']=p\mathbb{E}[X_CY_CZ_C],$$ where $X_C=X-\mathbb{E}[X]$, etc. Note that $\sigma_P=\sigma_X$, etc. The coskewness of $P,Q,R$ is $p$ times the coskewness of $X,Y,Z$, which was chosen to be $\alpha/p$.