# $E[(e^{Z}-C)^+] $ mean. Black-Scholes coefficients.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

If $Z$ is a standard normal distribution  $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $C> 0$ a constant,
$$E[(e^{Z}-C)^+] \text{ where} ^+ \text{entails only where the variable is positive }$$
I need to prove the mean is equal to:
$$e^{1/2}\phi(1-\log(C))-C\phi(-\log(C))$$
where $\phi$ is just the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

I am really struggling to find it out but I am really stuck in the variable changes. It is part of the Black-Scholes equation coefficients.

Thanks and regards for your help.

---

EDIT: Thanks to epartow for your answer.

I guess that my approach was totally wrong. Just to summarize:

1. I try to get the probability density function:

\begin{align}
f_x&=\frac{d}{dx}P_x[X<x]=P_x[e^z<x-C]=P_x[\ z < \log (x-C)] \\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\phi(\log (x-C))=\varphi(\log (x-C))\frac{d}{dx}(\log (x-C)) \\
&=\varphi(\log (x-C))\frac{1}{(x-C)}=\frac{1}{(x-C)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\log^2(x-C)}{2}}.
\end{align}

2. Since it should be integrated only when $e^z-C>0$, the integretation for the mean shold be done between $\log C$ and $\infty$.
3. So for the mean we have to add $x$ to the density function so the integration should be:
   $$\int_{\log C}^\infty\frac{x}{(x-C)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-\log^2(x-C)}{2}}dx.$$
   Changing variable $\log (x-C) = y$ the integral should be:
   $$\int(e^y+C)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy,$$
   but the limits are:
   $$\int_{\log [\log(C) - C] }^\infty$$

Could you explain to me where is my failure and why epartow is correct? I can understand the normal standard property:
$$1−ϕ(x)=ϕ(−x),$$
as well as all the maths after setting the integral, but I don't understand how you get the mean with this integral instead of the probability density function multiplied by $x$.

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: What integral do you have to calculate? Please write that out.

Comment: If I unravel the edit history correctly you received a transparent and correct answer by epartow, then accepted it and then added to OP a lengthy and confusing explanation why your approach was wrong. Why did you do that? It diminishes the quality of the post and makes it hard for others to learn from it.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences. I am sure that epartow answer is right since it match the expected outcome. The only point, and it entirely due to my lack of knowlegde is that I dont understand how the mean of a function is calculated by the function multiplied by the standard dentisty function instead of assessing the density function and multyply by the weight. Sorry if I make it more confussing.

Comment: When $Z$ is $N(0,1)$ the mean of any function $f(Z)$ is undoubtedly the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(z)\phi'(z)\,dz\,.$  This is the smart approach that epartow took. If you want to do it the hard way you can figure out what the PDF of  $f(Z)$ is (use correctly the change of variable formula) and integrate $X=f(Z)$ against that PDF. The sign in front of $C$ in your formulas seems wrong and you have messed up the integration bounds.

Comment: Thanks for you clartification. My onlye remaning doubt is how to prove that  the mean of any function f(Z)  is undoubtedly the integral ∫+∞−∞f(z)ϕ′(z)dz. I will try to look for more info. Thanks again and best regards.

Comment: Dear @Kurt, I have been struggling how to find out that the if Z is N(0,1), why the mean is  ∫+∞−∞f(z)ϕ′(z)dz. Could you give me anu clue? Should I open a new post? Thanks a lot for your support and patience.

Comment: Here is an almost too elaborate [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4238451/949989).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by Sassatelli Giulio, we will use the identity
\begin{align}
 1 - \phi(x) = \phi(-x),
\end{align}
i.e. symmetry of the density of the standard Gaussian. We calculate
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(e^z - C)_+] = \int_\mathbb{R} (e^z - C)_+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz = \int_{z > \log(C)} (e^z - C) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz.
\end{align}
We continue by splitting the latter integral into two summands. It holds
\begin{align}
\int_{z > \log(C)} (e^z - C) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz &= 
\int_{z > \log(C)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}(z-1)^2} \, dz - C \int_{z > \log(C)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{z > \log(C)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{- \frac{(z-1)^2}{2}} \, dz - C (1 - \phi(\log(C))) \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{z > \log(C) - 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{- \frac{z^2}{2}} \, dz - C \phi(-\log(C)) \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{2}} (1 - \phi(\log(C) - 1)) - C \phi(-\log(C)) \\
&= e^{\frac{1}{2}} \phi(1 - \log(C)) - C \phi(-\log(C)).
\end{align}