# Expected value of Function Using Definition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I'm familiar with the following formula for expected value:

$E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x P(X=x)$

My professor said that for a function $g(X)$ it's true to write:

$E(g(X)) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} g(x) P(X=x)$

And he said that we can prove this using the definition but it's not so easy.

But, why this needs to be proved at all? I mean if $X$ is a random variable so is $g(X)$ so we just need to put $g(X)$ instead of $X$ in the definition and that's a clear and direct proof...

What's wrong with my approach and is there any formal proof?

Comment: It's not the same, because if you plugged in $g(X)$ directly you'd get $\sum g(x)P(g(X) = g(x))$.

Comment: You are correct about $Y = g(X)$ being a random variable, but applying the definition to $E(g(X))$ results $E(g(X)) = E(Y) = \sum_y y P(Y = y) = \sum_y y P(g(X) = y)$, where the sum is taken over all possible values of $g(X)$. Hence, the proof is about showing that it’s the same as the sum over $x$ that you’ve mentioned.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei hi, Is there any formal proof for this one? I couldn't find in google (pretty sure there is one but my search skills aren't that great as I'm not native speaker)

Comment: You can find many sources on the internet. This is one of them.(https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mean-lotus.html)

Comment: This is sometimes called the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Etymology).  For the proof you're looking for, see [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mean-lotus.html).  Also note, many people take the second equation (the one you're trying to prove) as the _definition_ of expectation, in which case there would be nothing to prove, and the first equation would just be a special case when $g(X) = X$. [EDIT: as I was writing this, I see @RahulBharadhwaj got there before me for the first link]

Comment: Also, this question has been asked many times before on this site.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243529/28641

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned considering $Y = g(X)$ as a different random variable and looking at $E(Y)$ we get
$$E(g(X)) = E(Y) = \sum_{y}yP(Y=y) = \sum_{y}yP(g(X)=y)=\sum_{x}xP(g(X)=x)$$
Obviously that didn't get us anywhere.

Anyways I'll write a proof I find intuitive.

Let $[P]=1$ if $P$ is true, else $[P]=0$. Now notice that
$$P(Y=y) = \sum_{x}P(X=x)\cdot [g(x) = y] = \sum_{\{x\ |\ g(x) = y\}}P(X=x)$$
(Basically to count $P(Y=y)$ go through all the values of $x$ and consider the probability contribution of only those for which $g(x)=y$, i.e we count the probability of $Y$ through $X$)

Knowing this we are basically done
\begin{align}
E(g(X))&=E(Y)\\
&=\sum_{y}yP(Y=y) \\
&=\sum_{y}y\sum_{\{x\ |\ g(x)=y\}}P(X=x) \\
&=\sum_{y}\sum_{\{x\ |\ g(x)=y\}}yP(X=x) \\
&=\sum_{y}\sum_{\{x\ |\ g(x)=y\}}g(x)P(X=x) \\
&=\sum_{x}g(x)P(X=x) \\
\end{align}

Edit: Apparently this does not work in general with discrete random variables, read the comments for further clarification.

Comment: This last equality is only true in general if the set of possible values of $x$ is finite.  If it is (countably) infinite, you need to assume absolute convergence to assure the equality.

Comment: @postylem That's true, I'll edit it for correctness. But in the question $x$ goes through $\{1,2,\dots\}$ so I didn't give it too much thought.

Comment: No, I mean _finite_ not countable.  Namely, if $\sum_x \left|g(x)\right| P(X=x)$ diverges, then $E(Y)$ is not defined; we'd say $Y$ has no finite expectation.  This is not possible if $X$ takes on only finitely many values, but it _is_ possible if there are countably many (see [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)).

Comment: @postylem I didn't pay attention to yoru first post, and to be honest I hadn't thought of such extreme cases.

Comment: Things work fine, you just have to assume $Y = g(X) \in L^1$, i.e., $Y$ has a finite first moment $E(|Y|) < \infty$.
Then you can move the summands around as you like by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat pedantic, so I won't edit it into the answer, but it is important to note for correctness that you must add this convergence caveat to the theorem: "$E(g(X)) = \sum_x g(x) P(X=x)$, for any discrete random variable $X$ and any real-valued function $g$, provided that $\sum_x \left|g(x)\right| P(X=x) < \infty$" (else, $E(g(X))$ is undefined).  Note, you need this caveat for the definition of E(X) to be correct as well.  Random variables don't necessarily have well-defined expectations.